# I'm having trouble centering a div

Tags: html, css

I have been reading everything but I'm not sure why i can not get the buttons to center under the top image. The .page_wrap margins are both auto?

I am trying to get the buttons to center on a desktop browser and samsung note 3 browser

```css
body {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/KH2LTHz.jpg");
}

.page_wrap {
    border:0px solid black;
    width:350px;
    height:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.space {
    border:0px solid black;
    width:250px;
    height:150px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], button {
    background: none;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/9qwHx0c.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0px;
    height: 71px;
    width: 227px;
    font-weight:200;
    font-size: 40px; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    /* add the rest of your attributes here */
}

img.shedremote {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/shedmine.css" />

<script>

var device = "http://192.168.1.178/";

function reqListener() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

function setLed(i, state) {
  if (state === undefined || state !== 'on') state = 'off';
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  if (i === 'all') {
    oReq.open("GET", device + "?all=" + state);
  } else {
    oReq.open("GET", device + "?led" + i + "=" + state);
  }
  oReq.send();
}

</script>

</head>


<body>
  
<div class="space"></div>

<img class="shedremote" src="http://i.imgur.com/wTL0PlY.png" alt="shedremote">

<div class="space"></div>

<div class="page_wrap">

  <table style="width:200%">
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="button" value="Lights on!" onClick="setLed(1,'on')"/>   </td>
      <td> <input type="button" value="Lights Off!" onClick="setLed(1,'off')"/> </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="button" value="door open" onClick="setLed(2,'on')" />   </td>
      <td> <input type="button" value="door locked" onClick="setLed(2,'off')"/> </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td> <input type="button" value="3 on" onClick="setLed(3,'on')" />        </td>
      <td> <input type="button" value="3 off" onClick="setLed(3,'off')" />      </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td> <input type="button" value="Disco on" onClick="setLed(4,'on')" />        </td>
      <td> <input type="button" value="Disco off" onClick="setLed(4,'off')" />      </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td> <input type="button" value="5 on" onClick="setLed(5,'on')" />        </td>
      <td> <input type="button" value="5 off" onClick="setLed(5,'off')" />      </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td> <input type="button" value="6 on" onClick="setLed(6,'on')" />        </td>
      <td> <input type="button" value="6 off" onClick="setLed(6,'off')" />      </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td> <input type="button" value="7 on" onClick="setLed(7,'on')" />        </td>
      <td> <input type="button" value="7 off" onClick="setLed(7,'off')" />      </td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
      <td> <input type="button" value="8 on" onClick="setLed(8,'on')" />        </td>
      <td> <input type="button" value="8 off" onClick="setLed(8,'off')" />      </td>
    </tr> 
  </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm curious -- why is the table "width: 200%"? And why is it inline (within the HTML) instead of in the CSS?

Comment: just learning and making mistakes

Comment: Just like all of us. :)

Answer (score 1):

To horizontally center the div itself:

```
/* If the div has the class "button-wrapper" */
.button-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or, to horizontally center the buttons within the div:

```
/* If each button has the class "button-centered" */
.button-centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

EDIT: I suppose you could keep using tables if you like. However, tables for layout is often not considered "best practice." For example, responsive design becomes more difficult because tables cannot automatically adapt to different screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you I did not know that. I wont use tables any more.

Comment: That is not the reason. If anything, tables are natively MORE responsive than the ordinary div. The reason is because semantically, tables are meant for tabular data.

Comment: There are a bunch of different reasons not to use tables for layout. Several questions on Stack Overflow discuss the issues at length... Arguably tables are OK for small-scale forms and button arrangements, and other special layout purposes. However, if you use tables to lay out the entire page (columns, etc.) then the page sections cannot rearrange themselves into a narrower/wider shape to fit a narrower/wider browser window.

Answer (score 0):

for your desktop problem i would try:

```
  .page_wrap
{
    border:0px solid black;
    width:500px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
body {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/KH2LTHz.jpg");
    width:100%;
}
```

and remove style from the html document.

another thing you   your page is not compatible for Samsung note 3 browser

you can try and work with [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to help fit your page for desktop and smartphone.

.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a play with that.